# Configuring maven deploy script with Android Experimental Gradle Plugin

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, gradle-experimental

I am working on adding NDK builds to a module of a library I already have deployed in maven. In the past, I used the stable Android Gradle plugin v1.5, but do to needs with the NDK build I am trying to use the experimental plugin (I need to specify a shared library to link against). The NDK build is fine, my issue is with my Maven deploy script.

At the end of my module's build script I call

```
apply from: '../maven_push.gradle'
```

After all the maven configuration stuff I have the following tasks:

```
task androidJavadocs(type: Javadoc) {
    source = android.sourceSets.main.java.sourceFiles
}

task androidJavadocsJar(type: Jar) {
    classifier = 'javadoc'
    //basename = artifact_id
    from androidJavadocs.destinationDir
}

task androidSourcesJar(type: Jar) {
    classifier = 'sources'
    //basename = artifact_id
    from android.sourceSets.main.java.sourceFiles
}

artifacts {
    //archives packageReleaseJar
    archives androidSourcesJar
    archives androidJavadocsJar
}
```

When I try to compile the build script I receive the following error:

```
Error:Could not find property 'android' on task ':moduleName:androidJavadocs'.
```

What is odd is that in Android Studio, autocomplete does find `android.sourceSets.main.java.sourceFiles` if I start typing. I know the experimental plugin is, well, experimental and I am also aware its poorly documented. Google is unfortunately not giving us any good options when it comes to automated building in this matter but I am hoping maybe someone understands enough about gradle to help me with this one.

Comment: did you find the way to fix it?

Comment: @TGIO No nothing yet. I noticed as we approach an Android N release that the tutorial samples have all updated to version 0.7 of the experimental plugin so I will be experimenting with that over the next few days.

Comment: also, upcoming android studio and gradle versions will introduce new and better way of manipulating NDK i think. We have just to wait for ASv2.3-4.